# Visual Basic: How do I run 2 loops simultaneously?

Tags: vb.net, loops, console, simultaneous

I am having problems with my code.

I am trying the have blinking icons either side of an option on a menu screen to signify the selection the user has currently. The problem is that I want to be able to simultaneously blink the cursor and read the key the user is inputting the move the cursor's position. Is there a way I can do this, or an easier way than the setup I currently have.

Any help is much appreciated as I am still learning, thanks.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim KeyPressed As String
    Dim Pos As Integer
    Dim MenuSelection As Integer = 1
    PreStuff()
    DisplayMenu()
    Cursor(MenuSelection, False)
    Do
        KeyPressed = GetKeyPressed()
        If KeyPressed = "ConsoleKey.DownArrow" And Pos = 1 Then
            MenuSelection = 2
        ElseIf KeyPressed = "ConsoleKey.DownArrow" And Pos = 2 Then
            MenuSelection = 1
        ElseIf KeyPressed = "ConsoleKey.UpArrow" And Pos = 1 Then
            MenuSelection = 2
        ElseIf KeyPressed = "ConsoleKey.UpArrow" And Pos = 2 Then
            MenuSelection = 1
        End If
    Loop Until KeyPressed = "ConsoleKey.Enter"
    Cursor(0, True)
End Sub

Sub PreStuff()
    Console.Title = "Populatio - Pre Alpha"
    Console.SetWindowSize(80, 25)
    Console.CursorVisible = False
End Sub

Function GetKeyPressed()
    Dim KeyChoice As String
    KeyChoice = Console.ReadKey().ToString
    Return KeyChoice
End Function


Sub Cursor(ByVal Op As Integer, ByVal State As Boolean)
    Do
        Select Case Op
            Case 1 And State = False
                Console.SetCursorPosition(32, 5)
                Console.Write("►")
                Console.SetCursorPosition(43, 5)
                Console.Write("◄")
                State = True
            Case 1 And State = True
                Console.SetCursorPosition(32, 5)
                Console.Write(" ")
                Console.SetCursorPosition(43, 5)
                Console.Write(" ")
                State = False
            Case 2 And State = False
                Console.SetCursorPosition(34, 7)
                Console.Write("►")
                Console.SetCursorPosition(41, 7)
                Console.Write("◄")
                State = True
            Case 2 And State = True
                Console.SetCursorPosition(34, 7)
                Console.Write(" ")
                Console.SetCursorPosition(41, 7)
                Console.Write(" ")
                State = False
        End Select
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    Loop Until Op = 0
    Console.SetCursorPosition(32, 5)
    Console.Write(" ")
    Console.SetCursorPosition(43, 5)
    Console.Write(" ")
    Console.SetCursorPosition(34, 7)
    Console.Write(" ")
    Console.SetCursorPosition(41, 7)
    Console.Write(" ")
End Sub

Sub DisplayMenu()
    Console.WriteLine("╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗")
    Console.WriteLine("║                            Populatio! By Alx                                ║")
    Console.WriteLine("╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣")
    Console.WriteLine("║                                                                             ║")
    Console.WriteLine("║                                 New Game                                    ║")
    Console.WriteLine("║                                                                             ║")
    Console.WriteLine("║                                   Exit                                      ║")
    Console.WriteLine("║                                                                             ║")
    Console.WriteLine("║                                                                             ║")
    Console.WriteLine("║                                                                             ║")
    Console.WriteLine("║                                                                             ║")
    Console.WriteLine("║                                                                             ║")
    Console.WriteLine("║                                                                             ║")
    Console.WriteLine("║                                                                             ║")
    Console.WriteLine("║                                                                             ║")
    Console.WriteLine("║                                                                             ║")
    Console.WriteLine("║                                                                             ║")
    Console.WriteLine("║                                                                             ║")
    Console.WriteLine("║                                                                             ║")
    Console.WriteLine("║                                                                             ║")
    Console.WriteLine("║                                                                             ║")
    Console.WriteLine("║                                                                             ║")
    Console.WriteLine("║                                                                             ║")
    Console.WriteLine("║                                                                             ║")
    Console.Write("╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝")
End Sub
```

Comment: Where in the `Do Loop` does `Op` change in order to terminate when `Op=0` ?

Comment: I think the limitation is with `Console.ReadKey()` which pauses exectution until a key is read. Unfortunately I do not have a workaround.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and put Option Strict On at the top of your code or set it in the project properties.  Some of your Function definitions don't even have return types specified.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you rip-apart the functionality problematically so that it can essentially run in a single loop - you would need to run each loop in a separate *thread*. A complex subject, but worth learning:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eed6swsx(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Although Multi-Threading maybe the way forward as Brad said, you maybe able to achieve what you want with the **DoEvent** method which tells the system to have a go at processing other events before continuing.

Try sticking DoEvents just before

```
    Loop Until KeyPressed = "ConsoleKey.Enter"
```

This will allow the Cursor method to run again so the loop will become...

```
Do
    KeyPressed = GetKeyPressed()
    If KeyPressed = "ConsoleKey.DownArrow" And Pos = 1 Then
        MenuSelection = 2
    ElseIf KeyPressed = "ConsoleKey.DownArrow" And Pos = 2 Then
        MenuSelection = 1
    ElseIf KeyPressed = "ConsoleKey.UpArrow" And Pos = 1 Then
        MenuSelection = 2
    ElseIf KeyPressed = "ConsoleKey.UpArrow" And Pos = 2 Then
        MenuSelection = 1
    End If
    DoEvents
Loop Until KeyPressed = "ConsoleKey.Enter"
```